# How to use Flyout in the WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF program I use library [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/). There is a button, after pressing which I want to display [Flyout](http://mahapps.com/controls/flyouts.html) control.

[image]

```
<Button Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" 
        BorderThickness="1"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2">

    <controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <controls:FlyoutsControl>
            <controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout" Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200">
                <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
            </controls:Flyout>
        </controls:FlyoutsControl>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Button>
```

But nothing happening when I press the button. Can't understand, why?

**Edit 1:**

**XAML:**

```
<Button x:Name="circleButtonSettings" Height="40" Width="40" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,5,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource MetroCircleButtonStyle}" 
        BorderThickness="1"
        Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Click="circleButtonSettings_Click">

    <controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout" Header="Flyout" 
                Position="Right" Width="200"
                IsOpen="{Binding OpenFlyOut, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text " />
        </controls:Flyout>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</Button>
```

**C#:**

```
public struct OpenCloseFlyOut
{
    public OpenCloseFlyOut(bool _isFlyoutOpen)
    {
        IsFlyoutOpen = _isFlyoutOpen;
    }

    public bool IsFlyoutOpen { get; set; }
}

public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    OpenCloseFlyOut obj = new OpenCloseFlyOut(true);

    // I call this method when press the button
    private void ChangeFlyoutState()
    {
        obj.IsFlyoutOpen = !obj.IsFlyoutOpen;
    }
}
```

After all it is still doesn't work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the IsOpen attribute that is bound to a bool property.

```
<controls:FlyoutsControl>
    <controls:FlyoutsControl>
        <controls:Flyout x:Name="yourMahAppFlyout" 
                Header="Flyout" Position="Right" Width="200"
                IsOpen="{Binding OpenFlyOut, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <TextBlock Text="Some text" />
        </controls:Flyout>
    </controls:FlyoutsControl>
</controls:FlyoutsControl>
```

Here is an example of how it works using the codebehind as your example above uses.

```
<Button x:Name="btnOpen" Content="open" Width="75" Click="btnOpen_Click" Height="20"/>
<Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="close" Width="75" Click="btnClose_Click" Height="20" Margin="221,125,221,175"/>
<Controls:FlyoutsControl>
    <Controls:Flyout x:Name="flyout">
        <TextBlock Text="Some Text"/>
    </Controls:Flyout>            
</Controls:FlyoutsControl>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        flyout.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        flyout.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```